# Batching in Android with RxJava window or buffer?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm looking to implement a batching mechanism before an api post for some simple event collection and logging.
Since this is Android, I also would like to handle lifecycle events for if this service is stopped, so what is the way to manually flush the buffered window if the service is stopped but the count or time has not been hit yet.

For example, I have a PublishSubject (subject), create a flowable and the perform a window operation on it like so:

```
subject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            .window(30,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    20,
                    true)
            .flatMapSingle { it.toList() }
            .subscribe (this::send)
```

If my service/app is paused or killed, I'd like to just send what is in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is to stop observing when necessary and flush current items in window. Documentation for `Flowable.window()` operator say this:

> When the source Publisher completes or encounters an error, the resulting Publisher emits the current window and propagates the notification from the source Publisher.

So you need to make your `Subject` emit error or complete. In most of the cases, this is not a correct way how to work with subjects. Let's replace `Subject` with something what can be easily completed:

```
private val stopObserver = BehaviorSubject.create<Unit>() // (1)

private fun emitStop() { // (2)
    stopObserver.onNext(Unit)
}

private fun sourceSubject(): Flowable<Long> { // (3)
    return Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .takeUntil(stopObserver.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)) // (4)
}

private fun runObservation() { // (5)
    sourceSubject()
        .window(10)
        .flatMapSingle { it.toList() }
        .doOnNext { Log.d("onNext", "${it.count()} items") }
        .subscribe()
}
```

Explanation of important parts:

1. Create new `Subject` which emits everytime you realize app to being stopped or paused.
2. You can simply emit `onNext` event to `Subject` when needed with function `emitStop()`
3. `sourceSubject()` function imitates your source `Subject`. This one emits item every second.
4. `takeUntil()` operator completes stream when passed `Publisher` (`stopObserver`) emits an item. This ensures, our overall `source Publisher` (`sourceSubject`) completes.
5. I have used simpler version of `window()` operator, but all of them use the same principle regarding to source publisher.

Possible output:

```
2019-11-30 10:48:54.527 D/onNext: 10 items
2019-11-30 10:49:04.524 D/onNext: 10 items
2019-11-30 10:49:14.525 D/onNext: 10 items
2019-11-30 10:49:19.056 D/onNext: 4 items
```